# Dictionary/Records to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert the dictionary to df?

```
data = {'records': [{'centre_contact_no': 1578},
                    {'centre_contact_no': 7517},
                    {'centre_contact_no': 3590}
                   ]
       }
```

I have tried:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: please provide the DataFrame of the expected output for clarity

Comment: "I have tried:" Okay, and **what happened** when you tried that? What should happen instead, and how is that different? What is the *specific* question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['records'])
```

output:

```
   centre_contact_no
0               1578
1               7517
2               3590
```

Or with a MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in data.items()}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
            records
  centre_contact_no
0              1578
1              7517
2              3590
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added extra `}` closing bracket in the dict which might probably not converting it to dataframe
After removing and running your code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'records': [
    {'centre_contact_no': 1578},
    {'centre_contact_no': 7517},
    {'centre_contact_no': 3590}
    ]
    }

data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print(data)
```

Output of the above code is:

```
                       records
0  {'centre_contact_no': 1578}
1  {'centre_contact_no': 7517}
2  {'centre_contact_no': 3590}
```

If you simply want row wise format, instead of `data` use `data['records']`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'records': [
    {'centre_contact_no': 1578},
    {'centre_contact_no': 7517},
    {'centre_contact_no': 3590}
    ]
    }
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data['records'])
print(data)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
   centre_contact_no
0               1578
1               7517
2               3590
```